# searching for a verse in the bible

Tags: python, text

i need help with this script

if it is in a different order in the text of the document then the picture will give a wrong result

input 27: 1: 1

and script da output

27: 1: 10

which is wrong would anyone help and modify the script? Thank you

if i have the file in a different order then the wrong result need to always find the result of what will be the input

```
userinput = input("Enter Book, Chapter, Verse:")
file = open("kjv.txt")
lines = file.readlines()
for line in lines:
    if userinput in line:
        print(line)
        break

file.close()
```

kjv.txt is bible text format

27:1:1 The Revelation of Jesus Christ which God gave him so that his servants might have knowledge of the things which will quickly take place: and he sent and made it clear by his angel to his servant John;

[image]

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  ```27:1:1``` will match ```27:1:1```, ```27:1:10```, ```27:1:11```...   Your code depends on how the text is ordered.

Comment: As others have said, it is matching correctly, it's just that there are multiple correct answers. A simple solution would be to add a space character at the end of your input, ie `if userinput + " " in line`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`userinput in line` looks for the input string as a substring anywhere in the line, it doesn't check for word boundaries.

Since the verse information is always the first word of the line, split the line and check if the first element is equal to the input.

```
userinput = input("Enter Book, Chapter, Verse:")
with open("kjv.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
        words = line.split()
        if len(words) > 0 and userinput == words[0]:
            print(line)
            break
```

Comment: invalid syntax ?

Comment: Sorry, fixed the typo